# Rendering Terrain Dynamically with Argument Buffers : Understanding why the particle buffer is not overwritten by the GPU inflight

Tags: objective-c, metal, wwdc

I am looking through an Apple demo project that is associated with the 2017 WWDC video entitled "Introducing Metal 2" where the developers demonstrate the use of argument buffers. The project is linked [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/rendering_terrain_dynamically_with_argument_buffers) on the page titled "Rendering Terrain Dynamically with Argument Buffers" on the Apple developer website. Here, they synchronize resource writes by the CPU to prevent race conditions with a `dispatch_semaphore_t`, signaling it when the command buffer finishes executing on the GPU and waiting on it if the CPU is writing data several frames ahead of the GPU. This is consistent with what was shown in a previous 2014 WWDC "Working With Metal: Fundamentals".

I noticed that it seems the `APPLParticleRenderer` is sending data to be written by the GPU in a compute pass before it finishes reading from that same buffer from the fragment shader from a previous render pass. The resource storage mode of the buffer is `MTLResourceStorageModePrivate`. My question: does Metal automatically synchronize access to private `id<MTLBuffer>`s accessible only by the GPU? Do render, compute, and blit passes called from new `id<MTLCommandEncoder>` have access to the buffer only after other passes have written and read from it (exclusive access)? I have seen that there are guaranteed barriers within tile shaders, where tile memory is accessed exclusively by the kernel before subsequent fragment shaders access the memory.

Lastly, in the 2016 WWDC "What's New in Metal, Part 2", the first presenter, Charles Brissart, at 16:44 mentions that fragment and vertex functions reading and writing from the same buffer must be placed into two render command encoders, but for compute kernels one compute command encoder suffices. This is consistent with what is seen within the particle renderer.

Comment: And right after commit `_frameAllocator->switchToNextBufferInRing();` And spawn in APPLParticleRenderer swaps parameters under each other for its kernel.

Comment: Yes I did see that. I also probably should have specified objective-c++ (I'm a Swift native and haven't worked on much objective-c). However, it appears that the `_frameAllocator` allocates only `_uniforms_gpu` and switches the buffer referenced there, writing into it each frame. There is a private `MTLBuffer` object managed by the particle renderer `_particleDataPool` (with `MTLResourceStorageModePrivate`) that is reused each frame which seems to be overwritten each frame while the GPU is still reading from it.

Comment: Tier 2 hardware

Comment: @OlSen It is possible I found my answer. According to the Apple documentation, a `MTLResource` has a default hazard tracking mode (`hazardTrackingMode`) of `MTLHazardTrackingModeTracked` (or `MTLHazardTrackingMode.tracked` in Swift). This means Metal tracks dependencies across commands that modify the resource, as is the case with the particle kernel, and delays execution until prior commands accessing the resource are complete. Hence, a triple buffering system is not needed for a resource accessed exclusively by the GPU (if it can be written to by the CPU, that is different)

Comment: niiice. can you write a proper answer below? would be beautiful for people who come from google

Comment: @OlSen I added more details after further researching Metal synchronization if you're interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment on the original question for a brief version of this answer.

It turns out that Metal tracks dependencies between commands scheduled to the GPU by default for `MTLResource` types. The `hazardTrackingMode` property of a `MTLResource` is defaulted to `MTLHazardTrackingModeTracked` (`MTLHazardTrackingMode.tracked` in Swift) according to the Metal documentation. This means Metal tracks dependencies across commands that modify the resource, as is the case with the particle kernel, and delays execution until prior commands accessing the resource are complete.
Therefore, since the `_particleDataPool` buffer has a storage mode of `MTLResourceStorageModePrivate` (`storageModePrivate` in Swift), it can only be written to by the GPU; hence, no CPU/GPU synchronization is necessary with a semaphore for this buffer and thus no multi-buffer system is necessary for the resource.
Only when a resource can be written to by the CPU while the GPU is still reading from it do we want multiple buffers so the CPU is not idle.

Note that the default hazard tracking mode for a `MTLHeap` is `MTLHazardTrackingModeUntracked` (`MTLHazardTrackingMode.untracked` in Swift), in which case **you** are responsible for synchronizing resource writes by the GPU

**EDIT**

After reading into resource synchronization in Metal, there are some additional points I would like to make that I think further clarify what's going on. Note that the remaining portion is in Swift. To learn more in detail, I recommend reading the "Synchronization" section in the Metal documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronization).

**MTLFence**

Firstly, a `MTLFence` is used to synchronize accesses to untracked resources within the execution of a *single* command buffer. A fence gives you explicit control over when the GPU accesses resources and is necessary when you are working with an untracked resource. Otherwise, Metal will handle this synchronization for you

It is important to note that the automatic management I mention in the answer only occurs within a single command buffer between encoding passes. But this does not mean we need to synchronize across command buffers scheduled in the **same** command queue since a command buffer is not immediately scheduled for execution. In fact, according to the documentation on the `addScheduledHandler(_:)` method of the `MTLCommandBuffer` protocol found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1442991-addscheduledhandler)

> The device object schedules the command buffer after it identifies any dependencies with work tasks submitted by other command buffers or other APIs in the system.

at which point it would be safe to access these same buffers. Note that within a *single* render encoding pass, it is important to mention that if a vertex shader writes into a buffer the fragment shader in the same pass reads from, this is undefined. I mentioned this in the original question, the solution being to use two render pass encoders. I have yet to determine why this is not necessary for a compute encoder, but I imagine it has to do with how kernels are executed in comparison to vertex and fragment shaders

**MTLEvent**

In some cases, however, command buffers in **different** queues created by the **same** `MTLDevice` need access to the same resource or depend on one another in some way. In this case, synchronization is necessary because the separate queues schedule their own command buffers without knowledge of the other, meaning there is potential for the two command buffers to be executing concurrently.

To fix this problem, you use an `MTLEvent` instance created by the device using `makeEvent()` and encode event signals at specific points in each buffer.

**MTLSharedEvent**

In the event (no pun intended) that you have multiple processors (different CPU cores, CPU and GPU, or multi-GPU), resource synchronization is needed. Here, you create a `MTLSharedEvent` in place of a `MTLEvent` that can be used to synchronize across devices and processes. It is essentially the same API as that of the `MTLEvent`, but involves command queues on **different** devices.